# Calculating land cover inside buffer zones using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, buffer, field-calculator

In one Shapefile I have created 1200 buffer zones Around coordinates. I created a field and calculated the buffer zones area in hectares.
Then I clipped different landcover layers to the buffer zones.
Now I want to calculate How many hectares of eg. Forest there are in Each buffer zone And afterwords the amount of felds, And so on.

The calculations shall be done in ModelBuilder.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Is your landcover raster or vector?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Intersect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000p000000) tool to intersect your land cover layers with your buffer layer. You can then recalculate the areas of each land cover layer within each buffer.

Comment: Follow the intersect and area calculation above with [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Summary_Statistics/00080000001z000000/), using the landcover class, buffer size, and unique ID field and/or X and Y fields for the coordinate as the case fields to help aggregate the calculation that sums the area.

Answer (score 0):

The [5.2.1 Multiple Ring Landscapes ACCRU Tool](http://www.biology.ualberta.ca/gis/?Page=3063#tools) can be used/modified to automate incremental buffering, intersecting, and dissolving. You will need to apply a conversion factor from the map units to hectares.